# Ejecutar SQL en Bash sin entrar en la consola de MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash

Es mi primera pregunta por aquí y aunque creo que debe existir una forma fácil de hacerlo, no la consigo encontrar.

Estoy creando un script en Bash para Wordpress y quería realizar las tareas comunes sobre la base de datos de forma desatendida (aunque antes el usuario introduzca los datos).

Y quería saber si puedo crear la base de datos, el usuario y asignar los privilegios sin tener que entrar en la consola de MySQL, para poder hacerlo directamente desde un script bash.

Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda, un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basándome en el primer párrafo de tu pregunta, creo que "wpshell" y "wpcli" te ayudarán bastante en lo que quieres hacer ya que con un comando en bash puedes hacer todo lo que necesitas.
Échale un vistazo a esto  https://wp-cli.org/es/ ya que está pensado para realizar tareas de mantenimiento y administración en wordpress sin usar un navegador web.

Respecto a crear la base de datos, wpcli tiene su propio comando "wp db create" con el que crea la base de datos siguiendo las opciones para decir qué usuario informar y demás.

Sin llegar a ese nivel, mysql tiene una opción de crear un fichero my.cnf en el home de root y con los permisos para que solo root pueda verlo por seguridad. En ese fichero my.cnf que es un formato .ini, puedes guardar el usuario y la contraseña del administrador del servidor mysql, y ejecutando el comando

```
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE <nombre>"
```

se crearía la base de datos sin pedirte las credenciales ni teniendo que guardarlas en todos los scripts a la vista de todos. Puedes investigar más al respecto sobre my.cnf y sus formatos, y sobre "mysql" comando que es básicamente el intérprete de mysql. Lo que sería "py" a un intérprete de python, o "sh" para bash.

Dicho todo eso, puedes hacer un script en .sh que simplemente ejecute todas esas cosas de una, incluyendo la creación de base de datos y diferentes comandos de wp para que termine todo el proceso de manera unattended.

Diviértete con eso que parece interesante.

Comment: Gracias!, no había pensado en usar WP-CLI para realizar la tarea. Con "wp db ..." creo que sería posible aunque tengo dudas sobre como asignar permisos al usuario para que pueda realizar la tarea. Lo probaré y confirmo si funciona!

Comment: he editado la respuesta para que puedas ver las opciones alternativas a wp cli. Si te va bien vótalo, es una alegría ver que otra gente puede buscar más rápidamente cuando una respuesta está confirmada como buena.

Comment: Estoy haciendo un script que partiendo de un Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server FRESH INSTALL haga absolutamente todas las tareas para crear un sitio con Wordpress de forma totalmente segura y rápida. Y eso incluye mucho de Hardening y Tune Linux. Con un servidor básado en NGINX, PHP8, MARIADB 10.5 y REDIS 6. Con ficheros totalmente personalizados para hacerlo, como digo, seguro y rápido. Voy por 1500 lineas de código y ahora estoy empezando con la instalación de Wordpress xDD. Gracias bro, lo pruebo y sin falta le doy a confirmar. Le he dado voto positivo pero al ser nuevo en la plataforma no se refleja

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta más bien deberías marcar la respuesta como correcta en lugar de solo votar positivo

Comment: En el momento de votar positivo aun no lo había comprobado, ahora si lo he hecho y ya está marcada como correcta. Gracias!

Comment: Gracias a ti y bienvenido

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado. Realmente era muy fácil una vez descubierto que podía ejecutar comandos SQL usando 'mysql -e "SQL". El comando `"mysql -e CREATE DATABASE wordpress DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;"` ha funcionado perfectamente. Al usar sockets para MySQL (MariaDB) no es necesario contraseña, así que basta con ejecutar los comandos necesarios para Wordpress con el usuario root o bien usando 'sudo'.

Mil gracias.